# FundMe.sol in code along

Tags: tutorials

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyMwXuJrbJQ&t=9348s
I was following the code along of lesson 4 of this tutorial.
I coded along FundMe.sol, which is supposed to transfer certain amount of eth if exceeds 50 usd.
[image]

However, when I deployed this code to the testnet, I found out that any number greater than 0 gwei does not get rejected. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to divide another time by `1e18` at the end:

```
uint256 ethAmountInUsd = (ethAmount * ethPrice) / 1e18 / 1e18;
```

It's because you divide once to bring the price to Usd (ethPrice / 1e18), and another time to get the amount in ETH (ethAmount is in wei).